# no visible global function definition for ‘median’

Tags: r

Since the latest R update I get the Note

> summary.xmlImport: no visible global function definition for ‘median’

in the CRAN check. Further notes refer to `read.table`, `write.table` and other standard functions in R.

When I have a look on my file summary.xmlImport, the file looks like this:

```
summary.xmlImport <- function(object, ...){

   rowCount <- sapply(object,nrow)
   cat("Summary of xmlImport object\n")
   cat("---------------------------\n")
   cat("Sequences    :",length(object),"\n")
   cat("Min hits     :",min(rowCount),"\n")
   cat("Average hits :",mean(rowCount),"\n")
   cat("Median hits  :",median(rowCount),"\n")
   cat("Max hits     :",max(rowCount),"\n")
   invisible(object)

}
```

I cannot understand, why I should add now the `median` function to the NAMESPACE, but why not the `min`, `mean`, etc. The note is only about the `median`function.

Anybody an idea what the reason for the Note is and how to fix it? I noted that there are tons of R packages that have currently the same Note.

I can understand this warning in the context of a non-declared variable, but I would assume that `median()`, `read.table()` and such functions are globally visible in R, especially as `mean()`seems to be!?

EDIT: I only receive the Note on CRAN, but not on my local computer what makes the search for the solution a bit nasty... The session info of my computer:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
```

Comment: Not sure it is related, but functions `length`, `mean`, `min` and `max` are from `base` and function `median` from `stats`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I assumed `median` would be also in `base`, I'll try to import the `stats` package to the NAMESPACE, maybe since in R.3.2.1 only the `base` functions are then globally visible...

Comment: According to Thomas's answer, it is the case.

Comment: I started a discussion on the package-devel-mailinglist for the same reason. Another suggestion was to add namespaces selectively.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As of [Monday June 29, 2015](http://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel/NEWS/2015/06/29#n2015-06-29), all non-**base** functions must be explicitly exported in NAMESPACE in order to pass `R CMD check --as-cran`. The change comes because code is now checked with only the **base** package attached, so functions from default packages (such as **stats**) must be listed explicitly.

To import these packages, consider doing the following:

- In DESCRIPTION, you probably want to list them in `Imports`. There is very little reason to ever list a package in `Depends`.
- In NAMESPACE, you can choose between `import(stats)` or `importFrom(stats, ...)`, where `...` is one or more comma-separated function names. (If you use `roxygen2::roxygenize()` or `devtools::document()` to generate documentation and NAMESPACE, the analogous markup would be `#' @import stats` and `#' @importFrom stats ...`.)

*If you want to work interactively with R in a mode that mimics this*, you'll want to start R with only the base package attached. [There are several ways to do this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html), but probably the easiest is to set an environment variable at your shell: `R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=NULL` or in the .Renviron file and then start R using `R --vanilla`. In Terminal or bash this would be:

```
$ export R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=NULL
$ R --quiet --vanilla
> search()
[1] ".GlobalEnv"   "Autoloads"    "package:base"
```

In Windows command prompt it would be:

```
C:\>SET R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=NULL
C:\>R --quiet --vanilla
> search()
[1] ".GlobalEnv"   "Autoloads"    "package:base"
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems it would be worthwhile to read R-Devel in the future.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, CRAN runs checks on R-devel (i.e., the daily release of R), so before you try to submit, you need to install that R version and run your package through its checks. They can change daily and without notice.

Comment: So what would the current recommended syntax be for these R core packages (eg stats)? How should they be included in the Description and Namespace - could you perhaps give the correct syntax? Under Depends or Imports?

Comment: @TomWenseleers Treat them like any other package. See edit.

Comment: So if I am using roxygen, should I include stats and so in in Imports then, and in any functions that use functions from stats put an @import stats then?

Comment: Related question is how I can set up my RStudio to only attach the base package by default, so that I can simulate the tests they are now done at CRAN? As I am having trouble with my package passing R CMD check --as-cran over here OK, but not at CRAN...

Comment: @TomWenseleers I have no idea about roxygen as I don't use that. Regarding the checks, just make sure you're running everything on the latest R-devel (i.e., the daily build), not the latest R release. That's probably the reason you're getting different results.

Comment: Thanks! I used the latest R devel windows build, https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rdevel.html, maybe I should use the latest Linux build, don' know? The @import in Roxygen then causes import(stats) to be added to NAMESPACE, is that OK?

Comment: @TomWenseleers Shouldn't matter whether you're doing Windows or Linux (unless you have compiled C/C++/Fortran/etc. code in your package, or a handful of other relatively rare cases). Seems like the roxygen approach should be fine, then.

Comment: Yes I was a little stumped by the fact that all checks were OK on my side, but not at CRAN. It must be some difference in their setup. The dependencies with the core R packages I managed to solve, but still there was some example code that wouldn't run on their side... I think it had to do something with a difference in their JAVA version perhaps...

Comment: Some general information related to this can be found at https://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/depends.html including using roxygen,@import and @importFrom