# no visible global function definition for ':='

Tags: r, tidyeval

I am writing a package that uses `tidyeval`. Because I use `tidyeval` I have rlang listed under imports in the description file.

One of the functions contains a few lines that use `:=`

Like this:

```
data %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      !!New_R := AP_R_X*!!X + AP_R_Y*!!Y + AP_R_Z*!!Z,
      !!New_U := AP_U_X*!!X + AP_U_Y*!!Y + AP_U_Z*!!Z,
      !!New_F := AP_F_X*!!X + AP_F_Y*!!Y + AP_F_Z*!!Z)
```

The code works as intended but I get the following note when running `devtools::check()`

```
 no visible global function definition for ':='
```

How can I get rid of this note? Is this not a part of rlang evaluation?

---

EDIT:
I have read the question "[no visible global function definition for ‘median’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132552/no-visible-global-function-definition-for-median), although the answers there explain why such a problem can arise. It does not explain why `:=` is not defined when I have imported `rlang`. I have edited the question to make this more clear.

Comment: Add an importFrom statement if you're using `roxygen2`. Not sure if this is from `data.table` or `rlang` or dplyr's `data.table` backend.

Comment: Not sure if this answer helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31132798/8506921

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no visible global function definition for ‘median’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132552/no-visible-global-function-definition-for-median)

Comment: I have joined @NelsonGon 's vote to close as a duplicate. To be fully specific on your context, it's from `rlang`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have updated the question as I don't think this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Could you link to the entire code if possible or add it to the question for more context?

Comment: Your update clarified the problem for me. Your issue is that you `Import` `rlang` in the `DESCRIPTION` file, but you **still** need `NAMESPACE` directives

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update from June 2023

You should run `usethis::use_import_from("rlang", ":=")`.

`usethis::use_import_from("rlang", ":=")` will import the `:=` function from `rlang` using the `@importFrom` tag in the package level documentation. For more information, check out the [documentation here](https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/use_import_from.html).

This will change you package level documentation to look something like:

```
@keywords internal
"_PACKAGE"

## usethis namespace: start
#' @importFrom rlang :=
## usethis namespace: end
NULL
```

Read more about this documentation in the [R packages book here](https://r-pkgs.org/man.html#sec-man-package-doc) and [here](https://r-pkgs.org/dependencies-in-practice.html#sec-dependencies-in-imports-r-code).

If you would like to use more `tidy-eval` functions from `rlang`, you should import them using `usethis::use_import_from()`.

`usethis::use_tidy_eval` has been marked as defunct as of `usethis 2.2.0` since it imports and re-exports an unnecessary amount of functions (see the [issue here](https://github.com/r-lib/usethis/issues/1656) and the [release notes here](https://github.com/r-lib/usethis/releases/tag/v2.2.0).

### Older Update (March 2023)

I wanted to add an update as of 2023 - you can now run `usethis::use_tidy_eval()` to handle this issue. The function will automatically import `rlang::dyn-dots`, or `` rlang::`:=` `` , along with `rlang::enquo`, `rlang::enquos`, `rlang::.data`, `rlang::as_name`, and `rlang::as_label` to take care of potential notes that will appear while using `tidyeval`. These will appear in a new file titled `utils-tidy-eval.R`. For a little more info, the documentation is [here](https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/tidyverse.html).

This function will essentially do the same thing as the accepted answer, but it creates a new file to hold these `@importFrom` functions, and it creates documentation for these imports within your package.

TLDR: Just run `usethis::use_tidy_eval()`

Answer (score 35):

After you updated your answer, to me, this is sort of on the line of whether it's a full duplicate or not. The only difference here is that you've added `rlang` to `Imports` in `DESCRIPTION` and haven't seen the difference between that and a `NAMESPACE` directive.

I mocked up an example package to show this isn't sufficient. First, I set up the package:

```
library(devtools)
create("anExample", rstudio = FALSE, open = FALSE)
```

Then, I add the example function from https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html to a file `R/my_mutate.R`:

```
#' A function
#'
#' @param df A dataframe
#' @param expr A variable in the dataframe
#'
#' @return The dataframe with new mean and sum columns
#' @export
my_mutate <- function(df, expr) {
    expr <- enquo(expr)
    mean_name <- paste0("mean_", quo_name(expr))
    sum_name <- paste0("sum_", quo_name(expr))

    mutate(df,
           !! mean_name := mean(!! expr),
           !! sum_name := sum(!! expr)
    )
}
```

Notice there are no `roxygen2` namespace tags. I make sure to add `rlang` and `dplyr` to `Imports` in `DESCRIPTION` and run `devtools::document()`. Then when I run `devtools::check()` I get the following:

```
my_mutate: no visible global function definition for ‘enquo’
  my_mutate: no visible global function definition for ‘quo_name’
  my_mutate: no visible global function definition for ‘mutate’
  my_mutate: no visible global function definition for ‘:=’
  Undefined global functions or variables:
    := enquo mutate quo_name

0 errors ✔ | 1 warning ✖ | 1 note ✖
```

However, if I change `R/my_mutate.R` to the following:

```
#' A function
#'
#' @param df A dataframe
#' @param expr A variable in the dataframe
#'
#' @return The dataframe with new mean and sum columns
#' @importFrom dplyr mutate
#' @importFrom rlang enquo
#' @importFrom rlang quo_name
#' @importFrom rlang :=
#' @export
my_mutate <- function(df, expr) {
    expr <- enquo(expr)
    mean_name <- paste0("mean_", quo_name(expr))
    sum_name <- paste0("sum_", quo_name(expr))

    mutate(df,
           !! mean_name := mean(!! expr),
           !! sum_name := sum(!! expr)
    )
}
```

When I run `devtools::check()` (after re-`document()`ing), I do not get that note.

Long story short, `Import` in `DESCRIPTION` is not sufficient. You also need `NAMESPACE` directives.

Comment: For easy access, put all your `@import` and `@importFrom` instructions in the header of `R/anExample.R`. See section 10.6 Documenting Packages -- https://r-pkgs.org/man.html

Answer (score 1):

See [Data masking and tidy selection NOTEs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/in-packages.html) in [Using dplyr in packages](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/in-packages.htm). The example is for `.data`, you can change it to `:=`.

Summarising you must do at the console:

```
usethis::use_import_from("rlang", ":=")
```

This command adds a line with the content `#' @importFrom rlang :=` in a file with the form `yourpackagename-package.R` that *Roxigen* understands and adds the necessary entry in the NAMESPACE file when you run `devtools::document()` (or any other command that does, as `devtools::check()`).