# How to manually add importFrom to NAMESPACE when roxygen2 auto-generates the file?

Tags: r, roxygen2

So I am working on compiling a package using the latest Rtools within RStudio.

I am getting this warning and suggestion:

```
Consider adding
    importFrom("stats", "IQR", "median", "na.omit", "quantile", "sd",
               "shapiro.test", "var")
    importFrom("utils", "read.csv", "write.table")
  to your NAMESPACE file.
```

I would like to add such functions as `na.omit` as they suggest in the NAMESPACE file.

However, that entire file gets auto-generated by roxygen2.  So how can I add them.

Can I add the importFrom syntax in the DESCRIPTION file?

Adding it to each function maybe a solution, but doesn't seem to be optimal.

Why roxygen2 doesn't have the file split into a MANUAL and auto-generated section is beyond me.

**How to manually add importFrom to NAMESPACE when roxygen2 auto-generates the file?**

Comment: Run `devtools::document()`. You may find this useful. https://laderast.github.io/2019/02/12/package-building-description-namespace/

Comment: I am using the GUI which calls devtools::document() ... the link was useful.  I ended up replacing na.omit with stats::na.omit ... trying to reference "rvest" syntax with the chaining '%>%' notation ... getting this warning/error: no visible global function definition for
    '%>%'

Comment: What if you add `@importFrom magrittr %>%` to your R script file to define your function(s)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58026637/no-visible-global-function-definition-for

Comment: Thanks, I was trying this `@importFrom rlang .data`

Comment: I got it to compile, have a notice: `unable to verify current time`

Comment: is there a way to force the homepage of the help files to organize functions by `@family` ?

Comment: Regarding the `unable to verify current time`, does this help? https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2019q1/003577.html

Comment: Q re: `@family` I don't know, I've never dealt with that.